# list and explanations of ways to boost this router's signal strength?

Tags: wireless-networking

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Improve Wireless Signal](https://superuser.com/questions/45960/improve-wireless-signal)  
>   [How to get wireless coverage over my whole house?](https://superuser.com/questions/55050/how-to-get-wireless-coverage-over-my-whole-house) 
>   [What's the best way to increase the range of my 802.11g router?](https://superuser.com/questions/29290/whats-the-best-way-to-increase-the-range-of-my-802-11g-router) 
>  
>   [The back of my house doesn't have WiFi Signal](https://superuser.com/questions/235384/the-back-of-my-house-doesnt-have-wifi-signal)

I'm interested in ways that are both specific to certain routers,  and generic.

When I say generic, I don't necessarily mean a one way that works for many.. but it can also be a generic answer, so mentioning solutions for different situations.

So not just the one router I mention.  Explanations are important, as well as all the ways.

One i'm particularly interested in boosting the strength of is this wireless router/modem Netgear VMDG280

maybe anywhere in a big house with three floors, maybe from the garden.

Comment: you'd be best off checking out this question for answers: http://superuser.com/questions/208270/wifi-poor-snr-reasons-and-solutions

Comment: @MaQleod  that doesn't really cover it.. Yes, I know boosters are an option, but with the booster option, i'd like to know the compatibility issues. And other ways too.

Comment: compatibility for antenna come down only to the connector, and there are adapters that will make anything work. Other than that, a simple signal booster is compatible with an router that uses the same wireless protocols. Honestly, you're best off cabling to each floor with an access point on each floor.

Comment: @MaQleod would wireless repeaters be cheaper than wireless access points?

Comment: I'm not sure, actually, but they function very differently. Repeaters will only work if the signal is strong enough to get to them in the first place. Cabled access points don't need a wireless signal to broadcast as they use the cabled connection. Depending on how much noise is between the repeater and the originating access point, a repeater may not even work.

Comment: If you're looking to boost the output of the router itself, you need to be careful not to exceed any restrictions in place by law in your area.